# Run bash commands and csh commands in same script

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, csh

I was going through a project and I saw there are two scripts:

**one runs in bash and other in csh.**

> Is there any way to merge both the files and run as a single script and one file only, means after merging there should not be the earlier files? This reduce the code size, and will be more user-friendly.

**For example:**

```
#!/bin/sh

setenv PROJ_ROOT $PWD
setenv PROJ_OS freebsd
setenv OS freebsd

#!/bin/csh
export ICP=`pwd`

#both /sh
if `uname -r | grep -c "10.2-RELEASE"` == 1 setenv PROJ_WITHOUT_THREAD 1
```

Comment: To start with the if statement at the end is syntactically wrong. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you rephrase the question to make it clearer?

Comment: The last 'if' checks for the OS version, that if its 10.2-Release, set that variable, that's it. I don't think anything more is needed to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Your example script doesn't make sense either way; a shell script cannot set variables in its parent process.

For a superficial compatibility hack, you could declare a function `setenv`; then most of your example script will run in `sh`.

```
setenv () {
    "$1"=$2
    export "$1"
}
```

Your `if` clause I believe will be a syntax error in both shells. I can't think of a way to write it portably, but my recommendation would be to abandon `csh` anyhow.

Comment: I know it doesn't make any sense but situation comes, I asked a possibility which can add to my knowledge. :)